# Why is this Segfault Occuring?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, interpolation

So I've traced the segfault to the line, but I don't understand why this is a segfault. Can someone elaborate on the error of my ways?

Here are the variable declarations.

```
size_t i, j, n, m, chunk_size, pixel_size;
i = j = n = m = 0;
chunk_size = 256;
pixel_size = 4;
```

Here are the array declarations.

```
uint8_t** values = new uint8_t*[chunk_size];
for (i = 0; i < chunk_size; ++ i)
    values[i] = new uint8_t[chunk_size];

float** a1 = new float*[chunk_size];
for (i = 0; i < chunk_size; ++i)
    a1[i] = new float[chunk_size];
```

And here is where the segfault occurs.

```
float delta, d;

for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    for (j = n = m = d = 0; j < 256; j = m) {
        while (i == 0 || d != 0) {
            d = a1[i][m];    <------SEGFAULT per GDB
            ++m;
        }
        delta = (d - a1[i][j]) / m;
        n = j + 1;
        while (n < j + m) {
            a1[i][n] = a1[i][n - 1] + delta;
            ++n;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to C++ and can't figure out why this would be a segfault. Is this not the proper way to set a variables value to a variable in an array? Is that the source of my segfault?

Note: The point of this whole thing is too expand a 4x4 array to a 256x256 array with my simpleton interpolation formula.

Comment: As soon as m is greater than or equal to chunk_size you're going past the bounds of your array. That would be my guess as to what it is.

I'd also recommend using meaningful variable names, i, j, n, m, and d are not very descriptive and make it harder to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Absolutely sure that `i` and `m` are in-bounds when calling `d = a1[i][m];`?

Comment: Your while loop has no safety against `m` growing out of range.

Comment: For which values of `i` and `m` do you get the segfault?

Comment: Wow, thank you all for the fast reply! I had completely overlooked `i` and it's bounds. That was only there for the initial condition so a do-while and the additional of `m < 256` seems to have been the remedy.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (i == 0 || d != 0) {
    d = a1[i][m];    <------SEGFAULT per GDB
    ++m;
}
```

This is an endless `while` loop, in some cases (e.g. in the first iteration of the outer loop).

Comment: an endless loop incrementing an array index => bang

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop starts out with `i = 0` and the inner loops starts with `d = 0` and the logic controlling the `while` loop is not sufficient (see code comment).

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    for (j = n = m = d = 0; j < 256; j = m) {
        // Here i == 0 is ALWAYS true (so d != 0 is ignored due to
        // short-circuit evaluation) and then 'm' is continuously incremented
        // until it goes out of bounds
        while (i == 0 || d != 0) {
        d = a1[i][m];    <------SEGFAULT per GDB
        ++m;
    }
    delta = (d - a1[i][j]) / m;
    n = j + 1;
    while (n < j + m) {
        a1[i][n] = a1[i][n - 1] + delta;
        ++n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following lines :

```
while (i == 0 || d != 0) {
        d = a1[i][m];    <------SEGFAULT per GDB
        ++m;
}
```

Your while loop will keep on going while `i` equals 0. Since you never increment `i` in your while loop, `m` keeps on incrementing forever until arriving out of bounds, causing the segfault issue that you are having.

Make sure you check the values of `i` and `m`, so that they are in the allocated memory range and your code will work.